# How to add shadow to input and custom icon using css

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on adding shadows to my custom icon and input. The current view is:

[image: current]

and the wanting output that I am looking for is:

[image: wanting]

I have been trying to add box-shadow, transparent background color, drop-shadow and this is the closest that I have achieved.

To mention, the arrow is an image: [image: arrow]

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../images/bg2.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 5px 15px 30px 15px;
  width: 500px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form-control {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.help-text {
  color: #FFFF;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #999;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

select,
input {
  background: #582e79;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px #582e79;
  color: #999;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #3c1f52);
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 135px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

.mt10 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.submit {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("../images/arrow.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  height: 23px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 135px;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="form-control mt10">
    <input type="text" id="discord-id-input" name="discord-id-input" placeholder="Discord ID">
    <button id="discord-id-button" type="submit" class="submit"></button>
  </div>
  <a class="help-text">ENTER DISCORD USER ID AND SUBMIT</a>
</div>
```

I wonder how can I add the shadow both to input and icon to be shadow like the wanting picture?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is not working by simply using `box-shadow`?

Comment: PS: Button is not an empty tag. it needs a closing tag instead of a slah at the end!

Comment: @tacoshy What I tried was to add box-shadow but when having box-shadow, nothing really happend (I did not see any changes/difference)

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the closing tag! Just updated the thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `box-shadow`-property liek this:

`box-shadow: 0 2px 0 Black;`

which has following syntax

`[horizontal offset] [vertical-offset] [blur] [color]`

```css
#discord-id-button,
#discord-id-input {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 black;
}

/* original CSS */
body {
  background-image: url('../images/bg2.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 5px 15px 30px 15px;
  width: 500px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form-control {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.help-text {
  color: #FFFF;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #999;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

select,
input {
  background: #582e79;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px #582e79;
  color: #999;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #3c1f52);
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 135px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

.mt10 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.submit {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("../images/arrow.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  height: 23px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 135px;
  outline: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 23px;
}

.submit:hover {
  background-image: url("../images/arrow-hover.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="form-control mt10">
    <input type="text" id="discord-id-input" name="discord-id-input" placeholder="Discord ID">
    <button id="discord-id-button" type="submit" class="submit"></button>
  </div>
  <a class="help-text">ENTER DISCORD USER ID AND SUBMIT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Tacoshy and thank you for the awesome example! This is how it looks with your example https://i.imgur.com/bNnZMXD.png - Its not quite the same as requested but what would I need to do to be able to do that in that case?

Comment: then remove the horizontal offset and choose a color that you like.

Comment: I guess im getting closer now https://i.imgur.com/koZtTS2.png :) but yet im not sure how to make the button in a same shape as the image, I tried to use `border-radius: 5px;` but is that right?

Comment: its hard to get what you want. You have to be mroe specific. What are you intend to achieve exactly. I not going to make the efford to "fix" the code to match closer to a low quality picture. Be as specific as you can (discribe it, not just post a picture)!

Comment: Oh okey! Im sorry, so what I am trying to achieve is the shape and the color of the "arrows" background. That looks like a rectangle but with rounded corners and that the color of the shape is darker than the background color

Comment: completely different question on how to style the button. The border radius for your image is 8px. So your button proberly should match it. As of now, you have no border-radius listed in your CSS for your button. If you want a darker color then your abckground color, just give it a lower RGB value then your background-color (what ever it is).

Comment: I assume I could add the `border-radius: 8px;` inside the `#discord-id-button,
#discord-id-input` to get the correct border radius? If I know understood it correctly right?